# Modal content breaking page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm hoping someone may be able to help?
I'm using a regular bootstrap modal to show information but whenever there's too much information in the modal body it breaks the page.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Hourly Jobs Information</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
 <h4><u>Hourly Contracts</u></h4>
          <p>We currently charge £25.00 per hour for jobs undertaken (with the first hour
            paid in full, regardless of completion time), then every hour entered into paid as a full hour.
            (e.g., If a shelf construction job takes 95 minutes, the team members time will be charged at
            £50.00.)</p>
            
            <p>However, if any hour (after the first hour) entered into does not go beyond the first half hour
            stage, a reduced fee of £15.00 will be charged for that shorter half hour.</p>
            
            <p>(e.g., If a painting job takes 75 minutes, the team members time will be charged at £40.00.)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="button2" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above absolutely fine, but any more content and it breaks the modal. This is the full content in the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Hourly Jobs Information</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<h4><u>Hourly Contracts</u></h4>
      <p>We currently charge £25.00 per hour for jobs undertaken (with the first hour
        paid in full, regardless of completion time), then every hour entered into paid as a full hour.
        (e.g., If a shelf construction job takes 95 minutes, the team members time will be charged at
        £50.00.)</p>
        
        <p>However, if any hour (after the first hour) entered into does not go beyond the first half hour
        stage, a reduced fee of £15.00 will be charged for that shorter half hour.</p>
        
        <p>(e.g., If a painting job takes 75 minutes, the team members time will be charged at £40.00.)</p>
        
        <h4><u>Materials</u></h4>
        <p>If materials are required for a job in advance the client can choose to
        either purchase these in advance for the team member, or the team member can purchase the
        necessary materials. The team member will discuss materials required with the client and costs
        can be agreed before the job begins. However, the client will be charged a one-off fee of £15.00
        for the time it takes the team member to purchase, order, collect the materials on their behalf.</p>
        
        <h4><u>Payment</u></h4>
        <p>Once the job has been completed, payment for the work done will be made with the team
        member there and then. We accept cash and card payments (sorry, no cheques) and are happy
        to provide a receipt for works completed, both physically and/or by email.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="button2" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would anyone have any idea why this might be happening? It's driving me bonkers!
Many thanks!

Edit:
Apologies, I should add that when visiting the page the rest of the menu system doesn't work until the modal is opened and closed.
Here's the page: http://fixnhelp.co.uk/dev/prices.html

Comment: Try to add the class `modal-dialog-scrollable` to your modal. I.e. `<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">`

Comment: Tried this, doesn't seem to work either :/

Comment: Look fine on my end ([link](https://postimg.cc/sQXV0STy)), what wrong on your end?

Comment: The menu breaks at the top until you open and close in desktop mode. You can't open the modal in mobile and it breaks the hamburger menu